# WP8 Side Loading Stopped Working

Tags: windows-phone-8, sideloading

Several weeks ago side loading was working on my windows phone 8 device.  I had installed a valid enrollment token (.aetx file).  I was able to successfully side load signed .xap files (either via downloading in IE or attaching to an e-mail).  All was good.

Then I ran down the battery and left the device for dead for over a week.  When I tried to run the old side loaded apps they worked.  But when I tried to side load a new xap I got an error message that said something about it having been too long since the enrollment token was verified with Microsoft.  I wish I'd written it down, because I can't get the error to show up again.

Now when I try to side load apps nothing happens at all.  It pops up the familiar dialog that confirms I want to install the app ("Would you like to install [my app] from [company name]?"), then I click install and the dialog disappears and the app isn't installed.

When I try to install the .aetx again it pops up the dialog to install, I click install, and then nothing (same as the first time).  Xap files still won't install.

Guessing that the phone needs to re-verify the enrollment token with Microsoft I tried waiting 24 hours, but that didn't help.  I'm running out of ideas.

In lieu of a direct answer, could someone help me at least get an error message?  Nothing shows up in the output window in Visual Studio when I try to side load while debugging an app and I'm not able to find any OS level error logs.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to install the aetx on another phone or did you try to reset your phone? You should also watch out for invalid date and time on the phone. I've run into similar problems with Lumias which keep on resetting to the 1.9.2012 7:00. The aetx was then declared invalid and was not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, it eventually started working for me again.  I can't recall now how long it took, about a week I think, but I'm guessing eventually it called home and re-activated the enrollment token.